# CCSprite not displayed correctly when using SpriteFrame

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xamarin, cocossharp

My iOS app (build with CocosSharp, Cocos2D port for Xamarin) runs at a design resolution of 640x960 pixels and I have some 64x64 sprites that are loaded from a spritesheet.
I'm using TexturePacker to create spritesheets and I configured it so it doesn't have any spacing between the frames.
Each frame is exactly 64x64 pixels and when I check the spritesheet it looks perfectly fine.

When I try to display CCSprites based on the frames (SpriteFrame) it keeps looking messed up when running on the device (iPhone 4)

If I save each frame as a separate sprite and display them, it works fine, but not when I display them using a SpriteFrame and the spritesheet.

Here is what it looks like on the device:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the simulator:

[image]

Anyone else experienced this?
All help is much appreciated, I've been stuck with this for a day now!

**UPDATE:**
Here is a little demo solution that demonstrates the issue (requires Xamarin iOS to build).
You can run it on a simulator or a device, both show the same issue.

[SpriteFrame_Issue.zip](http://blog.rumargaming.com/demo/SpriteFrame_Issue.zip)

Comment: is this a .pvr ? what version of cocos2d ?

Comment: It's a PLIST that contains the frames. It's CocosSharp 1.5.1 which is a port of Cocos2D. The issue also occurs if I manually specify the CCRects for the sprite frames.

Comment: ok ... not certain why you would need to code the texture crop for a frame with the C# version ... but fwiw it looks like a fence-post issue to me ... texturePacker plists are typically 0-based for position.

Comment: But why would it work perfectly fine in the simulator then?

Comment: Added demo code that shows the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not tooled to 'play out' csharp ... but : plist ok, texture ok, code looks good. This issue is a 'cropping' issue, not a rendering issue.

It reminds me of a frequent issue around here for background scrollers, getting a 1 px offset out of nowhere between 2 adjacent textures ! Turned out it is related to 'under the hood' int->float->int conversions, mixed in with scale-ups/scale-downs that end up buying you an extra pixel as offset, from 'float' rounding. Best i can offer is 'go look in the library' for that kind of anomaly, focus on the 'spriteFrame' code base.  Hint : the simulator is 64 bits, the iPhone 4 is not.

Comment: You're a genius! The 64/32 bit difference never occurred to me, but it makes perfect sense! I will discuss this with the CocosSharp folks and see if it's possible to fix it. In the mean time I've created the spritesheets with the options "extrude: 1, border: 2, padding: 2" which visually fixes it for the most part because "extrude" adds some extra pixels on the outside of each frame